# Izimodal iframe isn't displaying

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, izimodal

My code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.min.js" integrity="sha512-8aOKv+WECF2OZvOoJWZQMx7+VYNxqokDKTGJqkEYlqpsSuKXoocijXQNip3oT4OEkFfafyluI6Bm6oWZjFXR0A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/css/iziModal.css" integrity="sha512-pH06JFjxM84j7iRF99/Cw7d9R9m2mVmEVr8oI0kK8gVkr461DI+8OYpQctHUrbmdOH7oaRyDRkkCVlQIQCFEiQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<a href="http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com" class="trigger" id="modal-iframe">Modal</a>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modal-iframe').iziModal('open', event); // Use "event" to get URL href
});
$("#modal-iframe").iziModal({
    iframe: true,
    iframeHeight: 800,
    iframeURL: 'http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com'
});
</script>
```

Tried

- switching from using iframe, button
- enabling, disabling iframeURL
- changing event to event.this, this (i'm a js noob)

Comment: Where is `#modal-iframe`?

Comment: i updated it (and it still doesn't work)